# Strange Webpage Content Movement

Tags: css, html, web-content

So I'm new to HTML, CSS, and the whole web development scene so I decided to learn by altering existing pages. The bellow is a template that I have altered to my needs to allow for my CMS. The problem is, is that the content moves every now and then to the most unliked position.

[image: Unliked content position]

I believe that there is something wrong with my CSS that is causing this problem.

Upon inspection of the `footer` and `site_content` divs, I have found pretty much no differences. But I don't know why it doesn't ALWAYS show up like this:

[image: Content positioning that's good]

The CSS is too large to put on here but the whole source can be found on [GitHub under OrangeCider](https://github.com/mastercork889/OrangeCider). However I am putting in the (what I think is) relevant pieces of code:

```
#main, #logo, #menubar, #site_content, #footer {
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}
#site_content {
  width: 837px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 24px 20px 37px;
  background: #FFF url(content.png) repeat-y;
}
```

**UPDATE:** So it seems that if I remove the `overflow: hidden;` from the `#site_content`, the content shows how it should, except there is text overlapping with the sidebar ontop of the footer. Could it be things with the overflow?

Comment: can you provide example of problem  in http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have some conflicting CSS rules here.  One thing you can try is the `!important` keyword.

```
#main, #logo, #menubar, #site_content, #footer {
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

Also, just to make sure that `float: left` isn't interfering with your styles, put `clear: both` on the `#site_content`.

```
#site_content {
  width: 837px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px 24px 20px 37px;
  background: #fff url(content.png) repeat-y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#main, #logo, #menubar, #site_content, #footer {
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}

#site_content {
 clear:both;
 width: 837px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px 24px 20px 37px;
 background: #FFF url(content.png) repeat-y;
}
```

try this css

Answer (score 0):

**Hey, you need to be sure the center block has block display and clear: both.**

So you should update your CSS due to this one:

```
#main, #logo, #menubar, #site_content, #footer {
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}

#site_content {
  width: 837px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 24px 20px 37px;
  background: #fff url(content.png) repeat-y;
}
```

That's it. Have fun!

Comment: Didn't work, oddly enough. I think that there's something in the other parts of the HTML? I'm updating my main post with some more details that I have just found out...

Comment: Although the problem is fixed, I will provide you with a JSFiddle. :) http://jsfiddle.net/c84t9ru1/